# org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'maven' not found

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have updated  my AGP(Android Gradle Plugin) from 4.2.1 to 7.2.1, and after updating when the project sync, its getting the error
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'maven' not found.
below is my top level Gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    buildToolsVersion = '30.0.2'

    minSdkVersion = 24
    targetSdkVersion = 32

    // Alert! Read this first...
    // for Photo release make sure to comment FFMpeg Library from build.gradle(:app),
    // also, in class FFMPEGWatermark.java comment the body of method videoMergeWithFFMpegMethod()
    // and imports of FFMpeg Library.
    photoAppVersionCode = 1136
    photoAppVersionName = '5.2.9'


    // Alert! Read this first...
    // for video release make sure to uncomment FFMpeg Library from build.gradle(:app),
    // also, in class FFMPEGWatermark.java uncomment the body of method videoMergeWithFFMpegMethod()
    // and imports of FFMpeg Library.
    videoAppVersionCode = 583
    videoAppVersionName = '2.1.9'
}
```

I have tried to apply plugin: 'maven', individually in each module but not get any success.